# Facebook Javascript API - Post status update

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to find a complete description of how to post a user status update to Facebook using the Javascript API.

I've looked at other questions and answers on stackoverflow and none of them provide useful answers (most of them just tell you to go look at Facebook's documentation... which is lacking for javascript)

The code I have logs the user in successfully, but i can't seem to request the permissions properly.

The Facebook response error looks like this:
(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

I've been trying to request the permissions AFTER they log in, so that permissions will be requested from them if they visit the web page and are already logged in. Unfortunately adding the following line doesn't work:

FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog('publish_stream');

Any help would be appreciated, but please don't just forward me to Facebook documentation on permissions or Javascript, I've gone through the docs on both, and just can't figure it out.

So far I have:

```
//Initialize facebook
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '243153685858721',
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });

      // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
      // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
      // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
      // will be handled. 
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) 
      {
        // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
          // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
          // have logged in to the app.
            FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog('publish_stream');
            FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response2) 
            {
                console.log(response);

                if (!response || response.error) {
                console.log("error");
                console.log(response2);
                console.log(response.error);
                alert("You haven't given our app permissions to post to your wall, please logout of Facebook, then back");
                } else {
                alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
              }
            });
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
          // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
          // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
          // like this, for two reasons:
          // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
          // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
          // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
          FB.login();
        } else {
          // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
          // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
          // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
          // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
          // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
          FB.login();
        }
        });
      };
```

Comment: I know you said not to forward you to the docs, but I'm not in a position to type up an answer at the moment. But if you check out the developer tools at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/javascript-console/ there is a host of executable examples including the code for a post (using the feed dialog) which might help show you the right direction or where you're going wrong.

Comment: I eventually got it working. Thank you :)